# Word 2010 TOC contains spurious text and diagrams from the body of text

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

When I generate the Table of Contents in Word 2010, It copies some diagrams, illustration and text from the body.  How can I correct this?

Comment: Everything in the TOC is supposed to come from styles defined as "headings".  Check to make sure you haven't accidentally included them in the headings styles.

Comment: Okay, let's get serious here: This is Word we're talking about. 90% of the answers to this question won't apply in 6 months because their UI never stays even remotely similar to previous versions. This is how you resolve most issues in Word: Find the problem, copy and paste the entire paragraph/section to a notepad file and delete the section from word. Be sure to include at least 3 or 4 lines *around* the text you're trying to fix. Paste in your copied text and reformat it all together. If it doesn't work the first time, delete more lines around your text until you can beat it into submission

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the paragraphs of the diagrams, illustrations and other text have their outline level correctly set under Paragraph properties. They should be "Body Text" and not "Level X".

Comment: Yeah, um, that box is grayed out as "Level 1" (or blank with enough lines selected).

Comment: If it's blank then it means it will apply that change to all selected paragraphs. If it's grayed out it might mean you have selected something other than paragraphs perhaps a table or image? Try one block of text at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I think blank means the selected lines have different values for that field; while grayed out means that I cannot change that field. I was seeing (i) grayed and "Level 1" and (ii) grayed and blank. In neither case was there any change to apply. You're right, case (i) was because I had an image selected. I managed to fix it by cutting each piece (text or image) and re-pasting it in the same place. Go figure.

Comment: @Frank, Glad to hear you got it sorted, Word can be funny sometimes. What you said and what I said it 100% correct, I think I should of made what you said clearer in my original reply though :) Let me know if you have any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, when drafting the document, you selected some text as part of heading and then "corrected" this selection by changing the font of the text. You can correct this error as follows.

Select the Home tab. Selecting the text appearing erroneously in your table of contents then selects a heading style over Styles. Change the style by clicking the Normal style. Rebuild your table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had diagrams that were in a "Heading 3" style based on how I had added space around them prior to inserting each one, and therefore showed up in the TOC - selecting each diagram and setting it to "Normal" style fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this problem for quite a while.

If the headings are indeed "Heading X" and the body text is indeed "Body Text", you still need to make sure there's an extra line between the heading and the body ('Enter' as opposed to 'Shift-Enter'), or the table of contents believes the body is part of the heading.

Answer (score 0):

If upon reviewing your TOC, you see that in addition to the heading, the actual text is also appearing in the TOC, then you need go to the View tab, and click on the button that says outline and then in the upper left click “outline.” You are now viewing the document with little bullets that show plus signs or other indicators. To see all levels, at the top left click all levels in the drop down box after “show levels”. (You can scroll through your document and when you click on a heading or line from the body of the text, you will see what level of text that is.) So now go to your problem area in the text of the document that keeps appearing in the TOC. You will see that it is ascribed the wrong level. You can fix that by highlighting it and then at the upper left click on the correct level from the drop down box (which may in your case be body text.) You can then X out of outlining view. Check your text. You may have to fix the formatting a little but the text will be at the correct level. Now update your TOC and the heading but not the text should appear in the TOC.